# $5$-Letter Word with $d$ occurring at least once

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Find the probability that a $5$-letter word (in English) contains the letter $d$ at least once.

I know that we can take the complement so the answer is $$1-\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^{5}$$

However, I am interested in solving it without taking the compliment, in other words by counting.

So far my reasoning is this: $\quad$ There are $5$ positions $d$ can be in, so the answer should be $$\frac{5\cdot 26^4}{26^5}$$

But it isn't. I am double counting. How else can I proceed? Or how can I fix the double counting?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: To learn how to fix the double counting, Google "inclusion and exclusion".

Comment: So can I use the approach I used? In other words, can I fix my way, or must I try a different way? @saulspatz

Comment: Yes, you can fix your way, using the principle of inclusion and exclusion.  Either look at the wiki, or one of the numerous examples on this site.

Comment: You must subtract the cases where $d$ occurs at 2 places, add cases where it occurs thrice, and so on.

Comment: For what it is worth, the set of five letter English words and the set of five letter combinations from the 26 letter alphabet are not the same.

Comment: For a random dictionary file I found, there were $5,567$ English words that were five letters long (actually, the dictionary is American-English, so 'ou' is often shortened to 'o'. So, the word 'color' is considered a 5-letter word. I found $786$ such words containing the letter 'd'. This is, obviously, just one choice of dictionary, but assuming the letter 'd' is distributed approximately the same across all dictionaries, this gives a reasonable approximation. $$\left|\left(1-\left(\dfrac{25}{26}\right)^5\right)-\dfrac{786}{5567}\right| \approx 3.7\%$$

Comment: So, it is *close*, but not very close to actual usage of the letter 'd' in the English language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to *inclusion-exclusion*, consider the probability of a ***d*** in each position if the previous positions are ***d***-free, to get:

$$\frac{1}{26}+\frac{25}{26}\frac{1}{26} +\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^2\frac{1}{26}+\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^3\frac{1}{26}+\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^4\frac{1}{26}$$

Comment: Fantastic, this is what I was looking for! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Okay now I am a little confused, it seemed super intuitive and really scratched the itch I had, but how did you come up with this exactly? It looked at first glance (an extremely inexperienced one) like the law of total probability, but I don't see how. In fact, this made sense to me, but I do know why! May you please further explain what is happening?

Comment: @Kam  Each term  $\left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{26}$ in the addition is the probability that ***d*** appears for the first time in position $n$. So this is a geometric distribution and the sum of the first $5$ terms is a value of the cumulative distribution function

Answer (score 3):

I have a way of doing it but it makes use of the fact binomial expansion $(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k} = b^n + \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k}$. Note that the summation starts from $k=0$ which is key here.

Note that $d$ is in the 5-digit word follows a binomial distribution with a random variable $D\sim B(5,p)$ where $p = \frac{1}{26}$. Then probability that letter $d$ comes atleast once is simply:

$P(D \geq 1) = \sum_{k=1}^{5}{5\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{5-k} = (p+(1-p))^5 - \underbrace{(1-p)^5}_{k=0 \ \text{case}} = 1 - \left(\frac{25}{26}\right)^5$.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This is really cool! I am just starting to learn distribution functions, so this will definitely help, thanks a lot :)

Comment: no worries. whenever you see these kind of questions (i.e. combinatorial questions), think of binomial distribution. Easiest way.